# Memory Ordering, Out of other Execution and Multi thread Safety

Tags: multithreading, memory, strict-weak-ordering

I have been reading on memory re-ordering lately. My question is with regarding to multi threading scenarios. Consider the example below:

```
A = 0;
B = 0;

Thread 1 on Processor 1                       Thread 2 on Processor 2

    A = 100;                                      while(B== 0);
    B = 1;                                       //access A here
```

I have been coding on X86-64 windows platforms and never considered that stores to A and B could be reordered (either  at compiler level or at hardware level) and I may end up with B = 0 in thread 2 and find A to be still 0. And never ran into any issues or pesky bugs with such a code. Is it because x86-x64 are strongly ordered and so are windows C compilers.

For such a code to be executing on any other platform with weakly ordered memory, do I need to make sure I update and access A and B within a lock (assuming the underlying lock implementation uses memory barriers and make sures the lock is released only after all the prior loads and stores are visible across all processor cores).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is it because x86-x64 are strongly ordered and so are windows C compilers.

Indeed, `X86` is a strongly ordered CPU that does not allow store reordering. So all CPU cores will observe the order emitted by the compiler.

However, `B` is modified  on processor 1, while read on processor 2. That is not allowed by the C memory model without synchronization (try maximum compiler optimization, it may stop working).

Although locking can be used to synchronize between cores, it may be problematic since your are spinning on `B`. If that happens with the lock acquired, processor 1 can not update the value.

A correct solution is to make `B` `atomic`. That will guarantee correct ordering on all levels.

Comment: LMimsey you mean to maximum optimization could enable compiler level re-ordering. I didn't get "This is not allowed in C memory model". Strongly ordered x86 should guarantee that A = 100 when B = 1 which is what the above example intends to get.

Comment: Also the next part of my question, on a platform with weakly ordered memory, do I need to take care that I update both A and B inside a lock. Do lock primitives on all OS platform internally insert memory barriers in the lock release logic because otherwise even locking might not guard against hardware memory access reordering.

Comment: Read/write access to a single memory location by 2 or more threads is a violation of the memory model rules (aka data race). The result is undefined behavior. For example, since your compiler may not expect `B` to be updated on core 2, it may simply take it out of the loop. The loop will then never exit.

Comment: If `B` is atomic (C11 atomics library), it is guaranteed to work even on the weakest of platforms. The compiler will insert the necessary memory barriers.